# custom substr php

Tags: php, regex, substring

With the following string:

```
$string='some text <photo id="id#" /> some text';
```

Make a substr that if the end of its string is a part of

```
<photo id="id#" />
```

then apply an extra chunk to complete

```
"<photo id="id#" />"
```

Example:

```
substr($string,0,15);
```

result is:

```
some text <phot
```

If this happens I need to end up with:

```
some text <photo id="id#" />
```

He, can't find the way of doing this. by the way id# is a random numeric value whose length won't exceed 3 chars. If regex is necessary to come up with a function.

Comment: Have you considered a DOM parser?

Comment: The tag you need to care of is just photo or yuou have to care about different ones too?

Comment: Please refrain from parsing HTML with RegEx as it will [drive you į̷̷͚̤̤̖̱̦͍͗̒̈̅̄̎n̨͖͓̹͍͎͔͈̝̲͐ͪ͛̃̄͛ṣ̷̵̞̦ͤ̅̉̋ͪ͑͛ͥ͜a̷̘͖̮͔͎͛̇̏̒͆̆͘n͇͔̤̼͙̩͖̭ͤ͋̉͌͟eͥ͒͆ͧͨ̽͞҉̹͍̳̻͢](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Use an [HTML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php) instead.

Comment: I only need to care about the photo tag

Comment: I am not parsing html, is a value from a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this:-

output:-

[image]

```
<?php

$str= 'some text <photo id="#xx"/> some test';
$parts = preg_split('~(</?[\w][^>]*>)~', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($parts);
echo htmlentities($parts[1]);


$str_new= 'some text <photo id="#xx"></photo> some test';
$parts_new = preg_split('~(</?[\w][^>]*>)~', $str_new, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($parts_new);
echo htmlentities($parts_new[1]);
echo htmlentities($parts_new[2]);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use regex, just use the PHP string functions:

```
$string = 'some text <photo id="id#" /> some text';
$newString = substr($string, 0, strpos($string, '>') + 1);
```